# link not opening in specified frame

Tags: html, href, linkedin-api, frameset

I am trying to open a my linked in page in a specified html frameset frame I have setup. however it wont open the link in the specified frame set, but the link is valid as I have double checked this. (I am trying to open the link in the frame named Middle)

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/xxxx-xxx-xxxxx/3a/292/26a" target="Middle">
<img src="../Images/Linkedin.png" border="0" alt="Link in with me" align="right"
     onmouseover="this.src='../Images/Linkedin_Rollover.png'"
     onmouseout="this.src='../Images/Linkedin.png'">
</img>
```

Perhaps I have missed somthing?

Comment: If your frameset (which you haven’t shown us) is also correct – then maybe the external site you want to display inside of your frameset doesn’t like that, and uses some kind of frame breaker to get out of there …?

Comment: the site link has a non standard formatting http://www.linkedin.com/pub/xxxx-xxx-xxxxx/3a/292/26a i have tryed to add a .html at the end but to no avail

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. Besides, that site sends an HTTP header `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` telling browsers that it should not be displayed in frames on any other domain – there’s little you can do about that.

Comment: Wel there ya go Í didnt know that